# relationship between VMA and ELF segments

Tags: c, unix, memory, execution, elf

I need to determine the VMAs for loadable segments of ELF executables. VMAs can be printed from `/proc/pid/maps`. The relationship between VMAs shown by `maps` with loadable segments is also clear to me. Each segment consists of one or more VMAs. what is the method used by kernel to form VMAs from ELF segments: whteher it takes into consideration only permissions/flags or something else is also required? As per my understanding, a segment with flags `Read, Execute`(code) will go in separate VMA having same permission. While next segment with permissions **Read, Write(data)** should go in an other VMA. But this is not case with second loadable segment, it is usually splitted in two or more VMAs: some with `read and write` while other with `read only`. So My assumption that flags are the only culprit for VMA generation seems wrong. I need help to understand this relationship between segments and VMAs.

What I want to do is to programmatically determine the VMAs for loadable segments of ELF with out loading it in memory. So any pointer/help in this direction is the main objective of this post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A VMA is a homogeneous region of virtual memory with:

- the same permissions (`PROT_EXEC`, etc.);
- the same type (`MAP_SHARED/MAP_PRIVATE`);
- the same backing file (if any);
- a consistent offset within the file.

For example, if you have a VMA which is `RW` and you `mprotect` `PROT_READ` (you remove the permission to write) a part in the middle of the VMA, the kernel will split the VMA in three VMAs (the first one being `RW`, the second `R` and the last `RW`).

Let's look at a typical VMA from an executable:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
00400000-004f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006f1000-006f2000 r--p 000f1000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006f2000-006fb000 rw-p 000f2000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006fb000-00702000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
[...]
```

The first VMA is the text segment. The second, third and fourth VMAs are the data segment.

### Anonymous mapping for `.bss`

At the beginning of the process, you will have something like this:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/maps
00400000-004f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006f1000-006fb000 rw-p 000f1000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006fb000-00702000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
[...]
```

- `006f1000-006fb000` is the part of the text segment which comes from the executable file.
- `006fb000-00702000` is not present in the executable file because it is initially filled with zeroes. The non-initialized variables of the process are all grouped together (in the `.bss` segment) and are not represented in the executable file in order to save space (1).

This come from the `PT_LOAD` entries of the program header table of the executable file (`readelf -l`) which describe the segments to map into memory:

```
Type    Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
        FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
[...]
LOAD    0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
        0x00000000000f1a74 0x00000000000f1a74  R E    200000
LOAD    0x00000000000f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0
        0x0000000000009068 0x000000000000f298  RW     200000
[...]
```

If you look at the corresponding `PT_LOAD` entry, you will notice that a part of the the segment is not represented in the file (because the file size is smaller than the memory size).

The part of the data segment which is not in the executable file is initialized with zeros: the dynamic linker uses a `MAP_ANONYMOUS` mapping for this part of the data segment. This is why is appears as a separate VMA (it does not have the same backing file).

### Relocation protection (`PT_GNU_RELRO`)

When the dynamic, linker has finished doing the relocations (2), it might mark some part of the data segment (the `.got` section among others) as read-only in order to avoid GOT-poisoning attacks or bugs. The section of the data segment which should be protected after the relocations in described by the `PT_GNU_RELRO` entry of the program header table: the dynamic linker `mprotect(addr, len, PROT_READ)` the given region after finishing the relocations (3). This `mprotect` call splits the second VMA in two VMAs (the first one `R` and the second one `RW`).

```
Type        Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
            FileSiz            MemSiz             Flags  Align
[...]
GNU_RELRO   0x00000000000f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0
            0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000220  R
[...]
```

### Summary

The VMAs

```
00400000-004f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006f1000-006f2000 r--p 000f1000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006f2000-006fb000 rw-p 000f2000 08:01 524453     /bin/bash
006fb000-00702000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

are derived from the `VirtAddr`, `MemSiz` and `Flags` fields of the `PT_LOAD` and `PT_GNU_RELRO` entries:

```
Type       Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
           FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
[...]
LOAD       0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
           0x00000000000f1a74 0x00000000000f1a74  R E    200000
LOAD       0x00000000000f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0
           0x0000000000009068 0x000000000000f298  RW     200000
[...]
GNU_RELRO 0x00000000000f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0 0x00000000006f1de0
          0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000220  R
[...]
```

1. First all `PT_LOAD` entries are processes. Each of them triggers the creation of one VMA by using a `mmap()`. In addition, if `MemSiz > FileSiz`, it might create an additional anonymous VMA.
2. Then all (well there is only once in pratice) `PT_GNU_RELRO` are processes. Each of them triggers a `mprotect()` call which might split an existing VMA into different VMAs.

In order to do what you want, the correct way is probably to simulate the `mmap` and `mprotect` calls:

```
// Virtual Memory Area:
struct Vma {
  std::uint64_t addr, length;
  std::string file_name;
  int prot;
  int flags;
  std::uint64_t offset;
};

// Virtual Address Space:
class Vas {
private:
  std::list<Vma> vmas_;
public:
  Vma& mmap(
    std::uint64_t addr, std::uint64_t length, int prot,
    int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
  int mprotect(std::uint64_t addr, std::uint64_t len, int prot);
  std::list<Vma> const& vmas() const { return vmas_; }
};

for (Elf32_Phdr const& h : phdrs)
  if (h.p_type == PT_LOAD) {
    vas.mmap(...);
    if (anon_size)
      vas.mmap(...); 
  }  
for (Elf32_Phdr const& h : phdrs)
  if (h.p_type == PT_GNU_RELRO)
    vas.mprotect(...);
```

### Some examples of computations

The addresses are slightly different because the VMAs are page-aligned (3) (using 4Kio = 0x1000 pages for x86 and x86_64):

The first VMA is describes by the first `PT_LOAD` entry:

```
vma[0].start = page_floor(load[0].virt_addr)
             = 0x400000

vma[0].end = page_ceil(load[1].virt_addr + load[1].phys_size)
           = page_ceil(0x400000 + 0xf1a74)
           = page_ceil(0x4f1a74)
           = 0x4f2000
```

The next VMA is the part of the data segment which as been protected and is described by `PT_GNU_RELRO`:

```
vma[1].start = page_floor(relro[0].virt_addr)
             = page_floor(0xf1de0)
             = 0x6f1000

vma[1].end = page_ceil(relro[0].virt_addr + relo[0].mem_size)
           = page_ceil(0x6f1de0 + 0x220)
           = page_ceil(0x6f2000)
           = 0x6f2000
```

[...]

### Correspondence with the sections

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000400274  00000274
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000400298  00000298
       0000000000004894  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000404b30  00004b30
       000000000000d6c8  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           00000000004121f8  000121f8
       0000000000008c25  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           000000000041ae1e  0001ae1e
       00000000000011e6  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          000000000041c008  0001c008
       00000000000000b0  0000000000000000   A       6     2     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             000000000041c0b8  0001c0b8
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             000000000041c178  0001c178
       00000000000013f8  0000000000000018  AI       5    12     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         000000000041d570  0001d570
       000000000000001a  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         000000000041d590  0001d590
       0000000000000d60  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS         000000000041e2f0  0001e2f0
       0000000000099c42  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000004b7f34  000b7f34
       0000000000000009  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS         00000000004b7f40  000b7f40
       000000000001ebb0  0000000000000000   A       0     0     64
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         00000000004d6af0  000d6af0
       000000000000407c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         00000000004dab70  000dab70
       0000000000016f04  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       00000000006f1de0  000f1de0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       00000000006f1de8  000f1de8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS         00000000006f1df0  000f1df0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          00000000006f1df8  000f1df8
       0000000000000200  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         00000000006f1ff8  000f1ff8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS         00000000006f2000  000f2000
       00000000000006c0  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         00000000006f26c0  000f26c0
       0000000000008788  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [25] .bss              NOBITS           00000000006fae80  000fae48
       00000000000061f8  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [26] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000fae48
       00000000000000ef  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

It you compare the Address of the sections (`readelf -S`) with the ranges of the VMAs, you find the mappings:

```
00400000-004f2000 r-xp /bin/bash : .interp, .note.ABI-tag, .note.gnu.build-id, .gnu.hash, .dynsym, .dynstr, .gnu.version, .gnu.version_r, .rela.dyn, .rela.plt, .init, .plt, .text, .fini, .rodata.eh_frame_hdr, .eh_frame
006f1000-006f2000 r--p /bin/bash : .init_array, .fini_array, .jcr, .dynamic, .got
006f2000-006fb000 rw-p /bin/bash : .got.plt, .data, beginning of .bss
006fb000-00702000 rw-p -         : rest of .bss
```

### Notes

(1): In fact, its more complicated: a part of the `.bss` section might be represented in the executable file for page alignment reasons.

(2): In fact, when it has finished doing the non-lazy relocations.

(3): MMU operations are using the page-granularity so the memory ranges of `mmap()`, `mprotect()`, `munmap()` calls are extended to cover full-pages.

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive reply. I got some new knowledge but I am afraid it does not provide the answer of my question

Comment: Well the answer is that the location of VMAs is given by the PT_LOAD and PT_GNU_RELRO entries.

Comment: ah ok i try to absorb this by tracing addresses in morning and come. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: plz correct me if wrong you want to say 006f1000-006fb000 is part of data segment (you typed text instead). what i got is that data segment has both initialized and uninitialized data. after split and mprotect, second vma (first data vma 006f1000-006f2000 ) represents .data section while 3rd vma 006f2000-006fb000 represents .bss. the location of split can be dtermined by .bss section addr. and which vma will have read only is decided by .got

Comment: 006fb000-00702000 represents heap ? I declared uninitialized array of 100 integers there was no heap when i declared array with 1000 integers it was shown in maps. Before and after array declaration code was using malloc but without array of 1000 ints there was no heap. what is connection of heap with .bss?

Comment: @shami, Yes, 006f1000-006fb000 is the non-initalized part of the data segment.

Comment: @shami, Use `readelf -S` to find which sections belongs to which VMAs.